# How to view the arguments that are passed to a system call in GDB

Tags: gdb

I am running PEDA with GDB. By default, I see the registers, stack and the code sections. However, when I set a breakpoint to a system call, I want to see the arguments that are passed to this system call. There is supposed to be an "arguments" section just like there is a registers, stack and code sections. I tried the "dumpargs" command, and it didn't work.

Do I have to modify the configuration file or something else?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to see the arguments that are passed to this system call.

On most OSes, arguments to system calls are passed *in registers*.

For example, on Linux/x86_64, the system call number is passed in `$rax` (e.g. `$rax == 0` for the `read` system call, `1` for the `write` system call, etc.), the first argument in the `$rdi` register, etc. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6).